# creates a new pandas column named "list_of_all_next_high" and populates it with lists of all next high values for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe for stock prices:

```
    dt                  open    close   high    low
0   2023-09-15 07:51:00 1.06521 1.06521 1.06525 1.06521
1   2023-09-15 07:52:00 1.06521 1.06520 1.06522 1.06520
2   2023-09-15 07:53:00 1.06520 1.06523 1.06524 1.06520
3   2023-09-15 07:54:00 1.06521 1.06532 1.06534 1.06521
4   2023-09-15 07:55:00 1.06533 1.06529 1.06534 1.06523
5   2023-09-15 07:56:00 1.06530 1.06529 1.06532 1.06525
```

I want to creates a new column named "list_of_all_next_high" and populates it with lists of all next high values for each row. the result will be like this:

```
    dt                  open    close   high    low     list_of_all_next_high
0   2023-09-15 07:51:00 1.06521 1.06521 1.06525 1.06521 [1.06522, 1.06524, 1.06534, 1.06534, 1.06532]
1   2023-09-15 07:52:00 1.06521 1.06520 1.06522 1.06520 [1.06524, 1.06534, 1.06534, 1.06532]
2   2023-09-15 07:53:00 1.06520 1.06523 1.06524 1.06520 [1.06534, 1.06534, 1.06532]
3   2023-09-15 07:54:00 1.06521 1.06532 1.06534 1.06521 [1.06534, 1.06532]
4   2023-09-15 07:55:00 1.06533 1.06529 1.06534 1.06523 [1.06532]
5   2023-09-15 07:56:00 1.06530 1.06529 1.06532 1.06525 []
```

I use this code to obtain the result, but it take very long time, the dataframe is 1 million rows.

```
df['list_of_all_next_high'] = [df['high'].iloc[i+1:].tolist() for i in range(len(df)-1)] + [[]]
```

Any other optimized method that can handle a large dataset (with more than 1million rows) to avoid consuming excessive resources?

Comment: There is certainly a better way to do this, you are essentially duplicating your entire dataframe into another column. Why do you want to build `list_of_all_next_high`?

Comment: for each row, I want to check if the trade will lost or won in case I sell/buy at this specific price. this mean that I will get the max of each list in the column "list_of_all_next_high". (I want the maximum high following each row)

Comment: Why not just store that max value then, or even better, just write your other functions to pull this value as required, without duplicating all the data throughout your dataframe?

Comment: I don't know how

Comment: Without seeing more of your code I'm afraid it is very difficult to help you reach a better solution

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution, which appears to be much faster than my other solutions. The idea of this solution is to use `numpy` and a triangular matrix ([`np.triu`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html)) as a mask. However, this approach demands a lot of memory (that you may not have available).

```
highv = df['high'].values
length = len(df)

m = np.triu(np.ones((length, length), dtype=bool), 1)

lists = [highv[m[i]].tolist() for i in range(length)]

df['list_of_all_next_high'] = lists
```

---

Another possible solution:

```
l = [df['high'].iloc[i:].to_list() for i in range(1,len(df)+1)]
df['list_of_all_next_high'] = l
```

---

Alternatively:

```
pd.concat([df, df['high'].iloc[::-1].shift()
           .map(lambda x: [x] if ~np.isnan(x) else []).cumsum()
           .rename('list_of_all_next_high')], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                    dt     open    close     high      low  \
0 2023-09-15  07:51:00  1.06521  1.06521  1.06525  1.06521   
1 2023-09-15  07:52:00  1.06521  1.06520  1.06522  1.06520   
2 2023-09-15  07:53:00  1.06520  1.06523  1.06524  1.06520   
3 2023-09-15  07:54:00  1.06521  1.06532  1.06534  1.06521   
4 2023-09-15  07:55:00  1.06533  1.06529  1.06534  1.06523   
5 2023-09-15  07:56:00  1.06530  1.06529  1.06532  1.06525   

                                      list_of_all_next_high  
0 2023-09-15  [1.06522, 1.06524, 1.06534, 1.06534, 1.06532]  
1 2023-09-15           [1.06524, 1.06534, 1.06534, 1.06532]  
2 2023-09-15                    [1.06534, 1.06534, 1.06532]  
3 2023-09-15                             [1.06534, 1.06532]  
4 2023-09-15                                      [1.06532]  
5 2023-09-15                                             []
```

Comment: Very similar logic ;)

Comment: Thanks, @mozway! Indeed, very similar logic, and it came almost simultaneously!

Comment: my computer crushed when using each of the 3 options

Comment: Not enough memory, I guess, @khaledkoubaa! The column you want to add will have 1000000 * 500000 = 500000000000 floats. Most probability, the result column does not fit the memory of your computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the values by date, then use a list comprehension:

```
s = df.sort_values(by='dt')['high'].tolist()
df['list_of_all_next_high'] = [s[i+1:] for i, x in enumerate(s)]
```

Output:

```
                    dt     open    close     high      low                          list_of_all_next_high
0  2023-09-15 07:51:00  1.06521  1.06521  1.06525  1.06521  [1.06522, 1.06524, 1.06534, 1.06534, 1.06532]
1  2023-09-15 07:52:00  1.06521  1.06520  1.06522  1.06520           [1.06524, 1.06534, 1.06534, 1.06532]
2  2023-09-15 07:53:00  1.06520  1.06523  1.06524  1.06520                    [1.06534, 1.06534, 1.06532]
3  2023-09-15 07:54:00  1.06521  1.06532  1.06534  1.06521                             [1.06534, 1.06532]
4  2023-09-15 07:55:00  1.06533  1.06529  1.06534  1.06523                                      [1.06532]
5  2023-09-15 07:56:00  1.06530  1.06529  1.06532  1.06525                                             []
```